# could you use fabricate to excavate a area of earth?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Could you use [fabricate](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/fabricate) to excavate an area of earth? if you cast the spell targeting the ground in a 120ft cube in front of you, could you clear out the area? If so, what would happen to the raw materials? It specifies you have to create something, but could you just create a single stone/similar?

Comment: the range is 120ft. The effect (for stone/mineral) is only a 5ft cube in the spell description. Compare the description of fabricate and stone shape to disintegrate. I will try to write up a proper response later

Comment: @Weiramon it says the fabricated item must be 5ft, the spell targets 120 square feet of raw materials i believe

Comment: I don't think so, the spell specifically says "Choose raw materials you can see within range." Further it states "You convert raw materials into products of the same material." However, I encourage checking the "Related" questions to the right hand side of the screen, they might give you a better answer.